# Vagrant disable Guest Additions

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I would like to disable VirtualBox Guest Additions. I do not use them for folder syncing, etc. and for the box I am working on (e.g., centos/7), they fail to build anyway. Is there some way to tell vagrant not to try to install them at `vagrant up`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In your Vagrantfile, add the following param

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    ....
    config.vbguest.auto_update = false
    ....
end
```

Comment: Make sure you install the [vagrant-vbguest plugin](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest) too.

Answer (score 16):

Users might not have the **vagrant-vbguest** plugin, and you could wrap its use in a conditional to avoid confusion.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  ....
  if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-vbguest")
    config.vbguest.auto_update = false
  end
  ....
end
```

Comment: can I install the plugin ? how?

Comment: That is another question...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74199862/571517