# issue with vagrant up with bento/ubuntu-18.04 on mac

Tags: vagrant, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to up a VM with bento/ubuntu-18.04, version 201803.24.0. I
am on a Mac running Sierra version 10.12.4, Vagrant 2.1.1.

The up fails with:

```
Package linux-headers-4.15.0-12-generic is not available, but is
referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'linux-headers-4.15.0-12-generic' has no installation candidate
==> web: Checking for guest additions in VM...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!
apt-get install -y linux-headers-`uname -r` dkms
Stdout from the command:
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Package linux-headers-4.15.0-12-generic is not available, but is
referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
Stderr from the command:
E: Package 'linux-headers-4.15.0-12-generic' has no installation candidate
```

From googling I think this may be related to my GuestAdditions
versions. During the up I see this message:

```
GuestAdditions versions on your host (5.2.12) and guest (5.2.6) do not match.
```

I ran 'vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest' which output:

```
Installing the 'vagrant-vbguest' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Installed the plugin 'vagrant-vbguest (0.15.1)'!
```

But I still got the same error with the same messages.

Anyone know what my issue is and how to fix it?

Comment: This does seem to be related to the vbguest installation. Adding `config.vbguest.auto_update = false` to Vagrantfile (per https://stackoverflow.com/a/37560913/326979 ) does seems to get me past this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but we ended up switching to CentOS to get around this issue.